# Entity Framework Apply Migrations Programatically

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to apply migrations through c# code using entity framework.
I want to drop certain tables(not all of them) and recreate programatically.
I have something like this:

```
try
{
    await dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("drop table if exists results");
    await dbContext.GetInfrastructure().GetService<IMigrator().MigrateAsync("20230104163600_AfterSync");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw;
}
```

I try to run specific custom migration which contains only some of the entities of the DbContext.
Here's the migration:

```
[DbContext(typeof(TempDbContext))]
[Migration("20230104163600_AfterSync")]
public partial class AfterSync : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "results",
            columns: table => new
            {
                id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
                groupId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("pK_results", x => x.id);
            });
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "results");
    }
}
```

If I remove the line

```
await dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("drop table if exists results");
```

It says:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'There is already an object named 'results' in the database.'

If I remove the override of `Down` method in the migration and leave the previous line, the application just crashes.

Can someone help how I can drop and recreate only certain tables not all of them withtout using the `database.Migrate()` method. Thanks

Comment: Why are you not letting the migrations remove the table?  You remove the entity classes from your code, create a new migration, and that should include the correct code to delete the tables.  You shouldn't be doing this manually.

Comment: What are you getting if keep **Both** the `await dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("drop table if exists results");` and verride of "Down". Down runs when you undo the migration and Up works when you apply the migration

Comment: @MukulKeshari If I keep both, it says that there is already an object with that name(as written above), but if I remove the override of "Down" and keep the line "drop table if it exists results", it worked like expected so that should be the solution for me. 
The main thing I want to do is to drop the tables so I can clear all the data(instead doing "delete from results" which is slower) and recreate the schema. 
If I do as @@Neil suggested I will delete the tables but then I need to recreate them